# Scrollable Flutter dialog, where the barrier scrolls instead of the dialog content

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a scrollable modal dialog in Flutter. But I don't want to scroll the contents of the modal. Instead, I want the modal to hug to its content vertically and have the barrier scroll when the modal is overflowing.

I tried something like the following:

```
   LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
            minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
            maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Dialog(...),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But now I cannot dismiss the barrier by clicking. Will I have to implement the modal from scratch? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Here are two screenshots to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Dialog overflowing (scroll top):
[image: Dialog overflow (scroll top)]

Dialog overflowing (scroll bottom):
[image: Dialog overflow (scroll bottom)]

Comment: Are you referring the top item will be fixed, and rest body component will be scrollable ? Can you include a GIF of your goal,

Comment: I don't have a GIF, but I added two screenshots, that hopefully show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work now. Here's how:

```dart
class ScrollableDialogLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ScrollableDialogLayout({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (context.canPop()) {
            context.pop();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent, // important, otherwise GestureDetector wont trigger
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: screenSize.height,
            minWidth: screenSize.width,
            maxWidth: screenSize.width,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: (){},
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => ScrollableDialogLayout(
    child: Dialog(...),
  ),
);
```

Not sure if there's a better way to do it...

Edit: I forgot to add that you need to wrap the `child` in another `GestureDetector`. Otherwise, clicking on the child will close the dialog as well. I edited my original code.